# From Gson to javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets, gson

It seems everyones using Gson to get JSON from a javascript file or just to exchange JSON in Java classes. I'm trying to send a Gson object to a javascript file but I'm not sure how to get the attributes from the Gson object inside my javascript file. I haven't found any tutorial explain something like that. I'd love to see a tutorial somewhere or have someone explain me how I should do this. I haven't used Gson before.

Comment: Simply use JSON.parse, assuming you don't use a library that does it for you.

Comment: @dystroy I'm having a small issue  but once I solve that I'll try JSON.parse and I guess you are totally right. thank you

Comment: @dystroy answer my question so I can give you the reputation you earned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON, whose name means JavaScript Object Notation, was designed to be easy to parse in JavaScript.

Historically you could use `eval` for that but now there's a dedicated function in all browsers : [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) : pass it your JSON string and it will return an object or an array.

Note that many libraries helping you query the server from a script running in a browser will also do the parsing for you so that you don't even have to call `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

dystroy is right.

Assuming you have read your GSON/JSON object into a javascript string, JSON.parse will create an object for you.

E.G.:

```
var myString = '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","nickName":"Johnny","title":"Mr","emailAddresses":["johndoe@example.com","john@example.com"]}'
var myObject = JSON.parse(myString);
// now we have an object with properties
console.log(myObject.firstName); // logs "John"
console.log(myObject.emailAddresses[1]); // logs "john@example.com"
```